# How to retain the state of inflated layout in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to retain the state of inflated layout while configuration changes, in android?
Can anybody provide some sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not cleat which part you have problem with. But anyway, take a good read of:

1. [Activity Lifecycle: Saving Activity state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState)
2. [Handling Runtime [Configuration] Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Also, all views with assigned id's usually save their state themself.

Answer (score 1):

Activity.onSaveInstanceState - save current state

Activity.onRestoreInstanceState - restore from saved state

More reading: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

Answer (score 0):

This is one trick I've learned to retain the current layout when configuration changes:
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/the-less-known-over-screen-orientation/